# G++ Not Finding Included .cpp Files When Compiling

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

`Inkey.cpp` and `Key.cpp` are in the same directory, */root/src*.

Compile.bat is in */root*.

When I run `Compile.bat`, I am given the message "Key.cpp: No such file or directory".

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Inkey.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Key.cpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << "Hello from InKey" << endl;

    Key key1;

    return 0;
}
```

Key.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Key {
    public:
        Key() {
            cout << "New Key instantiated." << endl;
        };
};
```

Compile.bat

```
@ECHO OFF

g++ "src/Inkey.cpp" -o "out/InKey.exe"

"out\Inkey.exe"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, rename `Key.cpp` to `Key.h`. Put the declaration in `Key.h`. Then put the definition in `Key.cpp` (Don't forget to include `Key.h` here). Then include your `Key.h` in all files using `Key` objects.
Now, compile them with `g++ -o filename.out file1.cpp file2.cpp -O3 -Wall`
Also, learn to use boilerplate code

> P.S. as @SoronelHaetir has suggested, use `""` to include custom header files

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation. In my ignorance, I thought I could pick up CPP during a Pet Project. Compiled languages seem a bit more involved than "interpreted" ones. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the difference between `#include "filename"` and `#include <filename>`. The former starts at the current directory, the latter uses a search path (or set of such paths). (Note that `#include "filename"` will fall back on the search strategy of `#include <filename>` if no file is found starting from the current directory).

Also, you do not usually include .cpp files, you pass them as separate arguments to the compiler and then combine them using the linker.